# Script to generate Markdown files with embedded PlantUML diagrams for GitLab's PlantUML renderer

Tags: python, bash, markdown, plantuml

I am setting up a repository to store software documentation consisting of several documents which are written in Markdown, and I want to be able to embed PlantUML diagrams in them. The repository is hosted in Gitlab, which includes a PlantUML renderer but does not allow [preprocessing](https://plantuml.com/preprocessing) and therefore using the `!include` clause to reference diagrams in other files.

I would like to have a bash or python script that:

1. Searches all .md files and append their content one after the other in a new file "all-docs.md".
2. Searches in that file "all-docs.md" for all the `!include [FILEPATH]` clauses and replace the content which is between `@startuml` and `@enduml` from that file [FILEPATH] into "all-docs.md".

For example:

"all-docs.md" contains in certain part:

```markdown
Here is the Profile class diagram:

``plantuml
@startuml
!include ./data-models/profile.puml
Profile o-- UidObject
@enduml
``
```

And profile.puml content is:

```
@startuml
class Profile <UidObject> {
    + string name
    + string email
    + string phone
    + Date birthDate
}
@enduml
```

The **result after the script** will be to have in "all-docs.md":

```markdown
Here is the Profile class diagram:

``plantuml
@startuml
class Profile <UidObject> {
    + string name
    + string email
    + string phone
    + Date birthDate
}
Profile o-- UidObject
@enduml
``
```

---

The repo has the following structure.

```
/
├── assets/
├── docs/
├── uml/
```

- The `assets/` directory contains various assets such as images, icons, and other resources.
- The `docs/` directory contains the documents (markdown files)
- The `uml/` directory contains contains [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/) source files that are used to generate diagrams for the software documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `bash` and `find` solution with your given input/files, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#: Find and concatenate all .md files from docs/ directory in all-docs.md file.
find docs/ -type f -name '*.md' -exec sh -c 'cat -- "$@" >> all-docs.md' sh {} +

#: Parse the all-docs.md file and 
#: create/print the desired result/output.
while IFS= read -ru "$fd" line; do
  if [[ $line == "!include"* ]]; then
    temp=${line#!include *}
    mapfile -t plum < "$temp" &&
    unset -v 'plum[-1]' &&
    printf '%s\n' "${plum[@]:1}"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  fi
done {fd}< all-docs.md
```

---

- Replace the last line of the code to

```
done {fd}< all-docs.md > tempfile && mv tempfile all-docs.md
```

- If you're satisfied with the output and permanent changes needs to be made for `all-docs.md`.

---

Or just parse the output of `find` directly without creating the `all-docs.md`, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Find all the files ending in .md in the docs/ directory
##: conCATenate all the contents of the files in question.
find docs/ -type f -name '*.md' -exec sh -c 'cat -- "$@"' sh {} + | {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line != "!include"* ]] && { ##: If line does not have the pattern !include.
      printf '%s\n' "$line"         ##: Print the line as is.
    }
    [[ $line == "!include"* ]] && { ##: If line has the pattern !include parse it.
      temp=${line#!include *}       ##: Extract FILE_PATH in a variable named temp.
      if [[ -s "$temp" ]]; then     ##: If variable is an existing non-empty file.
        mapfile -u3 -t plum 3< "$temp" && ##: Extract the desired result.
        unset -v 'plum[-1]' &&
        printf '%s\n' "${plum[@]:1}"
      else
        printf '%s\n' "$line"  ##: Otherwise just print the line as is.
      fi
    }
  done
}
```

---

If creating the `all-docs.md` is a must/requirement, then change the last line to:

```
} > all-docs.md
```

---

- Both `mapfile` aka `readarray` and `{fd}` requires `bash v4+`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution myself using Python.

1. Get a list of markdown files in the source "docs" directory and sort them based on their index prefix (files are named "0.introduction.md", "1.general.md", etc):
2. Define a new function called `replace_include_with_content`. This function takes a line as input and checks if it matches the pattern for the !include clause. If it does, it extracts the include path, constructs the relative path to the corresponding uml file, reads its content, and returns it. Otherwise, it returns the line as is.
3. Iterate through the sorted markdown files, read their contents. Within this loop, iterate over the lines of each file's content. For each line, we call the `replace_include_with_content` function to check if it needs to be replaced.

```py
import os
import re

docs_dir = "docs"
uml_dir = "uml"
output_file = "all-docs.md"

# Get a sorted list of markdown files in the source directory
markdown_files = sorted(
    [file for file in os.listdir(docs_dir) if file.endswith(".md")],
    key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0])
)

# Replace function
def replace_include_with_content(line):
    # Check if the line matches the pattern for !include clause
    match = re.match(r"!include\s+(.+)", line)
    if match:
        include_path = match.group(1)
        uml_file_path = os.path.join(uml_dir, include_path)
        # Read the content of the referenced UML file
        with open(uml_file_path, "r") as uml_file:
            uml_content = uml_file.readlines()
            filtered_content = []
            include_next_line = False
            for uml_line in uml_content:
                if uml_line.strip() == "@startuml":
                    include_next_line = True
                elif uml_line.strip() == "@enduml":
                    include_next_line = False
                elif include_next_line:
                    filtered_content.append(uml_line)
            return "".join(filtered_content)
    return line

# Open the output file in write mode
with open(output_file, "w") as outfile:
    for file in markdown_files:
        # Open each markdown file in read mode
        with open(os.path.join(docs_dir, file), "r") as infile:
            content = infile.readlines()
            for line in content:
                # Replace the !include clause with the content from the referenced UML file
                replaced_line = replace_include_with_content(line)
                outfile.write(replaced_line)
        outfile.write("\n")
```